# How to make my bot send message in a specific channel in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

PROBLEM

I dont know where I am wrong but the below code seems to throw me NoneType error even though I have used this thing in my other cogs too.

CODE

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=10.0)
async def remind(self):
    remind_channel = self.bot.get_channel(#id of channel)    
    await remind_channel.send("Passed")
```

ERROR

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

I am sure there is no mistake in channel id and also I am new to tasks so if this problem is arising due to it how do I solve it?

Comment: That literally means the channel was not found. Double check if you inserted the correct channel ID.

Comment: Yes I did and i check it thrice :(

Comment: Also its the same channel which I used in my command function just above the tasks snd it works fine

Comment: Try adding `await self.bot.wait_until_ready()` before you assign `remind_channel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NoneType` means in that case that either the channel id is invalid or the channel is not in the bot's cache because he's starting currently or whatever.

But in most cases, is the channel just not in the bot's cache.

You should add `await self.client.wait_until_ready()` at the start of the task, to wait until the bot's cache is ready.

Like this:

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=10.0)
async def remind(self):
    await self.client.wait_until_ready()
    remind_channel = self.bot.get_channel(#id of channel)    
    await remind_channel.send("Passed")
```

---

### Sources

- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_until_ready#discord.Client.wait_until_ready